# powershell stdout/stderr during executing (.foreach{})

Tags: powershell

How can I get stdout/stderr directly when executing a powershell script calling commands?

example:

```
$choco="C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe"
$chocoPackages = @('googlechrome','firefox','selenium-chrome-driver','selenium-gecko-driver')
$chocoPackages.foreach{ & "$choco" install $_ --yes --force 2>&1 }
```

But I do not get any output until the entire array is finished/failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that's how .foreach{} works.  Try foreach(){}  or foreach-object{}

```
(1..5).foreach{$_;sleep 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6)?

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe" `
              -ArgumentList "install", $_, "--yes --force" `
              -RedirectStandardError .\InstallError.log -RedirectStandardOutput .\InstallOutput.log
```